Wordpress - port_merged_resources folder
On my WordPress installation under the uploads folder there's a folder named porto_merged_resources, which contains thousands of .css & .js files.
All of the .js files have the same header
"/*!
 * jQuery blockUI plugin
 * Version 2.70.0-2014.11.23
 * Requires jQuery v1.7 or later
 *
 * Examples at: http://malsup.com/jquery/block/
 * Copyright (c) 2007-2013 M. Alsup
 * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses:
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 * http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
 *
 * Thanks to Amir-Hossein Sobhi for some excellent contributions!"

It takes nearly 20gb of storage. If I delete it then it will just regenerate itself.
Can't find info on what it is and if I need it or not.
I've tried deleting it, no success cause it regenerates.
tried using google but cant find anything with that folders name.
Edit: I checked a backup that was a few months old and that didn't have the folder. Only plugin that's been added is wp allimport pro.

Are you using the Porto theme? There's a thread about it here: https://www.portotheme.com/forums/topic/porto_merged_resources-growing-big/. If that's what you are using, you might be best to ask them.
